# In a bar graph can the lower numbers be made to have the taller bars?

Tags: chart.js

The situation is lower numbers are better. Take a ranking on a leader board as an example. If you are number 1 your ranking is higher than if you are 100th place. Yet the bar graph of the rankings will look like 100th place is more important because the bar is higher.

How can the sizes of the bars be reversed so the lower numbers have the higher bars?

Comment: 100 - rank.....

Comment: Keep in mind show 1 higher than 100 it's possible but this very very unfriendly data-visualization. It's better to use tables for such kind of data. Any manipulation you made on the data effect also tooltips (If you change "1" to "100" and "100" to "1" you also should change the tooltip data and so on = tidy).

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are 100 participates in the leader board, you can simply go through each piece of data and subtract 100, and then take the absolute value.

1st Place: 0 => |0-100| => 100

100th Place: 100 => |100-100| = 0